# iPhotos > Shared Photo Albums: Protect from Remote Deletion

Tags: photos.app, album

Several ***iPhoto*** *Shared Albums* disappeared after the person who shared the albums with me deleted them.

***Is there anyway I can safeguard pictures in Shared Albums even if the Album they were shared from is deleted at some point in the future?***

Answer (score 1):

If the person who shared the Albums either deletes them, or their account is otherwise deleted, your access to the shared albums will also cease. However, if you want to ensure future access to the shared pictures, you must copy the pictures locally to your own ***iPhotos*** account.

In ***iPhotos***:

1. Click on Shared Album
2. Click "***Select***"
3. Choose all the photos you want to protect from the sharer deleting the *Shared Album* (even or losing their account completely)
4. Click "***Share***" button
5. Choose "***Save Image***"

Now if the person who shared the album deletes it, you've copied the images into your own ***iPhotos*** account.  In the age of this global pandemic, I suspect a lot of cherished family photos will be lost forever as the virus claims loved ones who obviously won't be paying the monthly ***iCloud*** storage subscription fees.

Hope this helps folks safeguard their cherished memories from inadvertent loss-